# Datetime to decimal to pull into matplotlib with Python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a `<type 'datetime.timedelta'>` object of `(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)` for `2:00:00` and I'm trying to convert that to `2.0` for two hours. Respectively if I have `datetime.timedelta(0, 9000)` for `2:30:00` I'd like it to return `2.5`.

I don't even have example code because I can't even understand how I'd do such a conversion.

Comment: trimmed tags as the plotting is un-related to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using python >= 2.7, you can use `total_seconds`:

```
hours = td.total_seconds() / 3600
```

If you are using python < 2.7, you can make your own total_seconds:

```
total_seconds = lambda td: (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6
```